# Does Android Things support PS/2 mouse or have library for it?

Tags: hardware, android-things, hardware-interface

I've just started playing with Android Things and noticed that I could not find anything about PS/2 support in its library. I am trying to hook up a TPM754 trackpoint module to my RPI3 so that I can possibly write a drive so I can use it.

As far as I am aware, the TPM uses PS/2 to communicate. Is there a way to do that in Android Things? I am not so experienced in programming a hardware so I do not see the overall steps I need to take to achieve what I want to do. So, I am learning as I go and would really appreciate if someone could give me a big picture.

Can someone give me pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easiest way is to use hardware adapters PS/2 to USB (like [that](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Green-USB-2-0-Type-A-Male-to-PS-2-Female-for-Keyboard-Mouse-Converter-Adapter-hc/252816801174?_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D56425%26meid%3Daae4ebea62564cfc9479eb1663d5da08%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D201991524241%26itm%3D252816801174&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851)), or if TPM754 didn't works via USB - pair of connectors PS/2 to RS-232 (like [that](https://www.ebay.com/itm/15cm-PS-2-6-Pin-Mini-Din-Male-to-DB9-Serial-9-Pin-Male-Mouse-Cable-Adapter/292953774197?epid=1723270452&hash=item443567d875:g:FgMAAOSwWB5cXrMi)) and RS-232 to UART (like [that](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M4PZA7R)) (also PS/2 to UART adapters exists, but seems they more expensive), or more exotic converters (e.g. PS/2 to I2C).

Comment: Almost none of these paths are likely to work, unless the peripheral itself is dual-mode PS2/USB.  Otherwise an *active* translating adapter is required.  The suggestions to go by way of RS232 are utterly unworkable nonsense - as in the original, your are confusing connector types with electrical and application protocols, when they are actually completely distinct subjects.